# Viewport in iOS / Android WebView

Tags: webview, viewport, ibm-mobilefirst, screen-resolution

In the main HTML file, the following lines for viewport are specified:

`<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">`

**Experiment:**

I have tried to update the `width` from `device-width` to `640` and added the following codes to a JavaScript file on initialization.

```
alert("Viewport - Width: " + $(window).width() + "Height: " + $(window).height());
alert("Device - Width: " + window.screen.width + "Height: " + window.screen.height);
```

**Result:**

1. Samsung Galaxy S3 (Resolution: 720 x 1280):

   (a) width=device-width & width=640:

   Viewport - Width: **360**, Height: **615**

   Device - Width: **720**, Height: **1280**
2. iOS Simulator iPhone (Retina 3.5 - inch):

   (a) width=device-width:

   Viewport - Width: **320** Height: **460**

   Device - Width: **320**, Height: **480**

   (b) width=640:

   Viewport - Width: **640** Height: **960**

   Device - Width: **320**, Height: **480**

**Question 1:** It seems to me that Android WebView is not based on the viewport setting. In the testing result, the viewport's width is 360 instead of 720. Where is the value "360" comes from?

**Question 2:** The resolution in iPhone retina 3.5 is 640 x 960. Is it because retina display so it returns 320 and 480 for width and height respectively?

Comment: Some resources: [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml) and [here](http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html).

Comment: Thanks. [Here](http://i-skool.co.uk/mobile-development/web-design-for-mobiles-and-tablets-viewport-sizes/") is another useful link mentioning the viewport size for different devices.

Comment: The link is broken, there's an extra " at the end. If you this link help you solve your problem can you please write it as an answer and mark it as Answered?

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:
Look at AndroidManifest.xml
Change "android:largeScreens" for true

Answer (score 0):

According to PPK, there are 3 viewport in mobile device. [[Read more]](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/)

and what the `window.screen.width` get is the ideal viewport size, that is to say, the width of iPhone's ideal viewport size is 320px, while the Android's is 360px.

This is linked with screen density, for example, an Andorid device with 720px screen width will zoom in 2x to match it's ideal viewport size.